# Can't delete reg trojan.agent (Malwarebytes)?

Tags: windows-registry, malware, trojan

I ran a full system scan with malwarebytes and found this:

Registry Keys Detected: 1
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run (Trojan.Agent) -> Quarantined and deleted successfully.

malwarebytes then prompted me to restart my computer, so I did.

I ran the scan after restart and found it again. Could someone help me remove this please? or tell me it's just a fail alarm?

Answer (score 0):

It may not be a false alarm what you should try doing is checking what is starting up when the computer starts up. Which if I remember correctly, seeing as I haven't been on a windows machine for a while, is `msconfig`. You will need to type this into the Command Prompt which can be found by typing "command" into the search on a windows vista or windows 7 if it is windows xp it will be under the accessories. This will pop up a window which may or many not need a password (mostly depending on if you are running xp vista or 7) and you will need to go to the tab that says "Startup" then there will a check list. You will need to turn off any of the startup items (by unselecting them) that do not have a name or that you are unable to read (ie: sbsv10sti) those tend to be programs that mess with the computer in undesired ways.